# Magento 2 Product Form Categories Sort Alphabetically From the Backend

Tags: magento2, category-products, sorting, category-tree

**I want to sort Categories alphabetically of the product form, how can I?**

For more clarification please look onto the below picture.

[image]

As I checked, by default Magento 2 sort according to the category id(ASC order).

I'm not getting the files so that I can check and modify sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Categories.php**

Following method is responsible for creating category tree.

```
protected function getCategoriesTree($filter = null)
{
```

You need to modify collection:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($shownCategoriesIds)])
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'is_active', 'parent_id'])
            ->setStoreId($storeId)->setOrder('name');
```

**NB: don't modify core file**